# MVC controller is not being called, but template controller works?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, webapi

I can't make heads or tails of what I'm doing wrong here. I'm calling a new controller I'm setting up using JavaScript fetch(). I'm using MVC 5 within the React template.
The template controller (WeatherForecastController) works, if I call it using fetch, it'll hit the controller. Yet using the exact same implementation but for a new controller it won't touch the new controller. However Network debugger shows that it called and returned OK. If I call the controller directly through the browser, it's as if there isn't a route for it at all! No json is returned from my new controller vs the template controller. I'm simply trying to define a new controller I can fetch data from my Middle tier (.NET 6). Using .Net 6.0 as well.

Naming convention is correct as it ends with Controller in call.

**DEFAULT TEMPLATE CONTROLLER CALL FROM JS**

```
async populateWeatherData() {
    const response = await fetch('weatherforecast');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
  }
```

**DEFAULT TEMPLATE CONTROLLER**
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

```
    namespace ReactTest.Controllers
    {
        [ApiController]
        [Route("[controller]")]
        public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
        {
            private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
            {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };
    
            private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    
            public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
            {
                _logger = logger;
            }
    
            [HttpGet]
            public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
               

 })
            .ToArray();
 

   }
}
```

}

Yet I call my controller I setup with the exact same implementation. If I try to call it I get exactly nothing!

**NEW CONTROLLER TEMPLATE CALL FROM JS**

```
async populateWeatherData() {
    const response = await fetch('database');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
  }
```

**IMPLEMENTATION OF NEW CONTROLLER** (That I actually want to call)
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

```
namespace ReactTest.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DatabaseController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<DatabaseController> _logger;

        public DatabaseController(ILogger<DatabaseController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried everything but modifying the default routing (the controller lives in the same folder as the template controller, so this shouldn't be why).

Before anyone asks:
**ROUTING CONFIG:**
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
[ProjectFileDirectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYWpj.png)
[DatabaseControllerResponseHeader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c0Be.png)
So what exactly am I doing wrong? Yes I have read the documentation, no it hasn't helped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you confirm that the `database` controller is not called? Both the controllers have the same code. Also both the call from JS have `await fetch('database');` is this a typo?

Comment: @Chetan that is a typo. I've corrected it. I meant to put 'await fetch('weatherforecast')'    As for my confirmation The best I've been able to confirm is if I were to call at (localhost:3000/database/database) I would get nothing back, whereas through the WeatherForecast controller, I'll get some json back from the method. Also the debugger breakpoint will hit in WeatherForecast, but not in DatabaseController.

Comment: Do you see any error? When you debug the controller code, does it hit the code inside the DatabaseController? Did you try using just `localhost:3000/database`?

Comment: That's the thing. It does show up as a call being made, returns as OK(200). But it's not actually pinging the controller.